# How does linear transformation preserves solution of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

I was reading a solution to a problem of IMO 1982.

Here is the problem

Prove that if n is a positive integer such that the equation $x^
3 − 3xy^2 + y^
3 = n$ has an integer solution (x, y) then it has at least
three such solutions.

In the solution of Titu andreescu,He used the fact that ,If $(x,y)$ is a solution to the equation then \begin{align*}x^3 -3xy^2 +2y^3 &=(y-x)^3 -3x^2y+2x^3\\&=(y-x)^3-3(y-x)x^2+(-x)^3\
\end{align*}
$\Rightarrow(y-x,-x)$is also a solution to the equation.\begin{align*}T\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}\begin{align*}&=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\\&=\begin{pmatrix}-x+y\\y\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Also,\begin{align*}
T^2
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
-1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
-1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\\&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 &-1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
under the linear transformations,$T, T^2$ on\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\end{pmatrix}, the solution of the equation $(x,y)$ proves to be valid. but how?
I don't know much about linear algebra but can anyone explain to me that how these solutions are kept valid by linear transformation?

Moreover, is there any normal algebraic version of this solution?

Comment: There is no need for linearity here, except to speed up the computation of $T^2 = T \circ T$. Linear or not, you have a transformation $T$ that stabilises the set of solutions, so if $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ is a solution then so is $T\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}, T^2\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}, T^3\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$, etc. It's then a matter of showing that we get three *distinct* solutions from this list (especially since $T^3$ is the identity map)!

Comment: @Theo Bandit, thank you.